# Не монтируется папка через docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1234"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - .\mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  php:
    image: "php:7.4-fpm"
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    env_file:
      - ./conf.env
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
    volumes:
      - D:\Михаил\homework:/var/www
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "9000:9000"
```

система WINDOWS 8.1 Профессиональная

```
D:\Михаил\homework\docker>docker-compose exec nginx /bin/bash
root@77f231a5127d:/# cd /var/www && ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root   60 Oct 28 11:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 28 11:37 ..
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root   60 Oct 28 11:29 docker
root@77f231a5127d:/var/www#
```

я ожидал там увидеть папки, которые у меня на локальной машине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вместо файлов и папок только папка `docker` с вложенной в неё папкой без файлов даже
Что я пробовал делать:

1. Всячески изменял путь к папке `D:\Михаил\homework` и с экранирующими слешами и с обратными слешами
2. Пробовал использовать относительные пути
3. Прибегал к различным форумам в том числе [этому](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/844)
   делал

   docker-machine rm default &&
   docker-machine create --driver "virtualbox" --virtualbox-boot2docker-url https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v18.09.8/boot2docker.iso default
4. Открывал Oracle VM VirtualBox и расшаривал эту папку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. После каждой попытки или изменения я делал команды

   docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build

Я новичок в docker

```
D:\Михаил\homework\docker>docker-compose up -d --build
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_db_1 ... done
Creating docker_php_1 ... done
Creating docker_nginx_1 ... done

D:\Михаил\homework\docker>docker-compose logs nginx
Attaching to docker_nginx_1
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

D:\Михаил\homework\docker>
```

Подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы заходя в `docker-compose exec nginx /bin/bash` и выполнив внутри команду `cd /var/www && ls -la` я смог бы увидеть там мои рабочие поддиректории `D:\Михаил\homework`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь `D:\Михаил\homework` точно работать не будет, так ка это путь на хост системе.

Нужно сначала эту папку сделать доступной внутри виртуальной машины. Т.е. в VM  примонтировать папку по какому-то пути, скажем `/mounted_win_drive`, и уже ту папку внутри VM использовать как volume в докере.

Делайте пошагово.

1. добейтесь чтоб папка с хоста была видна в VM
2. добейтесь что эта папка была видна внутри докера после команды типа `docker run -v /mounted_win_drive:/data nginx ls /data`
3. потом уже используйте примонтированую папку в `docker-compose`